# Why in HackerRank I am getting wrong answer for the correct mysql code?

Tags: mysql, sql, binary-tree

In HackerRank the problem "[Binary Tree Nodes](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/binary-search-tree-1/problem)" states that:

> You are given a table, BST, containing two columns: N and P, where N represents the value of a node in Binary Tree, and P is the parent of N.
>
> [image: Table content]
>
> Write a query to find the node type of Binary Tree ordered by the value of the node. Output one of the following for each node:
>
> - Root: If node is root node.
> - Leaf: If node is leaf node.
> - Inner: If node is neither root nor leaf node.

My mysql code is:

```
select case
            when N in (select P from BST) then
                case
                    when P is null then concat(N,' Root')
                    else concat(N, ' Inner')
                end
            else concat(N,' Leaf')
        end
from BST
order by N;
```

But I am getting the wrong answer as my output is:

```
when N in (select P from BST) then
case
when P is null then concat(N,' Root')
else concat(N, ' Inner')
end
else concat(N,' Leaf')
end
1 Leaf
2 Inner
3 Leaf
4 Inner
5 Leaf
6 Inner
7 Leaf
8 Leaf
9 Inner
10 Leaf
11 Inner
12 Leaf
13 Inner
14 Leaf
15 Root
```

Instead of

```
1 Leaf
2 Inner
3 Leaf
4 Inner
5 Leaf
6 Inner
7 Leaf
8 Leaf
9 Inner
10 Leaf
11 Inner
12 Leaf
13 Inner
14 Leaf
15 Root
```

Why is this happening ?

Comment: Your query should give the correct output in this case, but the method is incorrect, as your SQL would set a root node with no child nodes as a leaf.

Answer (score 0):

It is a glitch in (or limitation of) the HackerRank parser for SQL input, which apparently cannot handle line breaks very well.

If you put at least all of the `case` expression on one line it will work, like so:

```
select
case when N in (select P from BST) then (case when P is null then concat(N,' Root') else concat(N, ' Inner') end) else concat(N,' Leaf') end
from BST
order by N
```